# How would I select a group of buttons using classes and if any of them are pressed, a alert pops up

Tags: javascript, html

I tried using .addEventListener with querySelector, but for some reason it wouldn't work.

```js
const b = document.querySelector(".buybttn");
b.addEventListener("click",() => {
    console.log("button was clicked");
})
```

The error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')`
I don't understand why the error is happening either.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        
        <noscript><p>You need to enable javascript to fully use this website.</p></noscript>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Space Pups Fan Website!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
            <center>
            <div class="navbar">
                <a href="./plushie.html" class="buttonA">Plushies!</a>
                <a href="./about.html" class="buttonA">About Space Pups</button>
                <a class="buttonA" href="Hidden for privacy"> TikTok </a>
            </div>
        </center>    
        <h1> Space Pups</h1>
        <h2>Stickers</h2>
        <center>
        <div class="products">

         <div class="product">
        <center>
            <img src="./Images/sticker1.png"> 
            <h3>Gold Sticker!</h3>
            <h4>2.99$</h4>
            <button class="buybttn">Buy!</button>
        </center>
         </div>         
            <div class="product">
            <center>
                <img src="./Images/sticker2.png"> 
                <h3>Moth Alien Sticker!</h3>
                <h4>2.99$</h4>
                <button class="buybttn">Buy!</button>
            </center>
            </div>  
                <div class="product">
                <center>
                    <img class="SpecialRose"src="./Images/sticker3.png"> 
                    <h3>Rose Pup sticker!</h3>
                    <h4>2.99$</h4>
                    <button class="buybttn">Buy!</button>
                </center>
                 </div>
               
                </div>
                <br>
              
        <div class="products">
                 <div class="product">
                <center>
                    <img class="SpecialBoss"src="./Images/sticker4.png"> 
                    <h3>Alien Boss Sticker!</h3>
                    <h4>2.99$</h4>
                    <button class="buybttn">Buy!</button>
                </center>
                 </div>     
                 <div class="product">
                    <center>

                    <img class="SpecialDia" src="./Images/sticker5.png"> 
                    <h3>Sleepy Dia Sticker!</h3>
                    <h4>2.99$</h4>
                    <button class="buybttn">Buy!</button>
                    </center>
                 </div>           
                 <div class="product">
                <center>
                    <img class="SpecialDia" src="./Images/sticker6.png"> 
                    <h3>Ghost Pup Sticker!</h3>
                    <h4>2.99$</h4>
                    <button class="buybttn">Buy!</button>
                </center>
                 </div>      

    </div>
   
        </center>
  
        </body>
        <script src="./script.js">
        </script>
</html>
```

Anyone have some knowledge they can share?
...................................................................
......................................................................................................................................
Thanks, Leo.

Comment: Check if the `buybttn` class is correct. And if it is then, check the scripts runs at the end of the `body`.

Comment: @FrancoA.Torres Yup.

Comment: The script is linked and the class is correct.

Comment: If you share your `html` markup I can try to see where the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get all the buttons with `document.querySelectorAll` and add an event in each one of them with the `forEach` method and `addEventListener`. You can access the value of a button with `event.target.value`.

Try the following `.js` code:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".buybttn").forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', event => alert(`Button ${event.target.value} was clicked`)))
```

Comment: Oh I understood something else. I'l change it.